# susdo apt-get install ./edgesdk-oauth-tool-setup-linux-1.0.0.deb does not work on raspbian

Tags: edgesdk, edgeengine

Not able to install oauth-tool due to the following issues.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Downloads $ sudo apt-get install ./edgesdk-oauth-tool-setup-linux-1.0.0.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
**Note, selecting 'edgesdk-oauth-tool:amd64' instead of './edgesdk-oauth-tool-setup-linux-1.0.0.deb'**
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 edgesdk-oauth-tool:amd64 : Depends: libgtk-3-0:amd64 but it is not installable
                            Depends: libnotify4:amd64 but it is not installable
                            Depends: libnss3:amd64 but it is not installable
                            Depends: libxss1:amd64 but it is not installable
                            Depends: libxtst6:amd64 but it is not installable
                            Depends: libatspi2.0-0:amd64 but it is not installable
                            Depends: libuuid1:amd64 but it is not installable
                            Depends: libappindicator3-1:amd64 but it is not installable
                            Depends: libsecret-1-0:amd64 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
pi@raspberrypi:~/Downloads $
```

Answer (score 0):

Sukanta, the package you are trying to install is amd64-based architecture, whereas Raspbian is ARM64-based. You need to install the package on an amd64 machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can also follow the steps below to get edge access token for raspberry pi node.

1) Install edgeSDK and oauthtool in your Windows/Ubuntu/MacOS ( PC platforms) 
2) Go to developer portal from your PC platfrom and run oauthttool 
3) In "Get OAuth 2.0 section, enter  the IP address of raspberry pi unit and click to get the edge Access token Token
4)oauthtool will display the edge access token for raspberry pi